# open your app from other app

Tags: android

I created an App for Playing MP3. Now I want to open my app from other apps like file explorer.
When the user clicks on any mp3 file it must show my app in "Complete action Using" like this:

**Complete action using:**

*[my app]*

*[other app 1]*

*[other app 2]*

*...*

When my app is selected, I want it to play the mp3 file (it should get the path to it somehow?).

How do I do this?

[Example here...](http://blog.laptopmag.com/wpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/complete-action-i.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply add an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)

add this:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="content"/>
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: thanks but this only solves first part of my problem
need help for second part too